# Backed up MySql folder… upgraded to newer version and cant seem to recover data

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0

I copied the entire MySql folder `mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64` and installed a newer version `mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64`.

I should have researched but thought the installer would handle moving the data over (I only backed up as a precaution).

After installing my older MySQL folder only has 'data' and 'keyring' and the new the obvious. My backed up folder seems to have everything the old MySQL did before the new install.

Is there a way to get the older data?

I've tried copying the data folder to the new install folder, data & keyring.

I'm on Mac. upgraded from MySQL 8.0.13 to 8.0.17

Old MySQL Directory:
`/usr/local/mysql-8.0.13-macos10.14-x86_64/`

Now after installing the update:
`/usr/local/mysql-8.0.17-macos10.14-x86_64/`

Comment: Within a major version (8.0), you should always be able to upgrade-in-place.  But be sure to run `mysql_upgrade`.  If you changed directories, that is another matter.

Comment: Hey, Rick. Thanks for the response. Not sure what you mean by changing directories. The installer installed in a directory with the mysql version number. Do you know if I can run mysql_upgrade after my situation?

Comment: Update your Question to show the old and new data directory paths.  There is probably a way to do the install and point it to the old directory.

Answer (score 0):

At this point, it is probably simplest to use `mysqldump` to dump the old data and load it into the new path.

Comment: I cant seem to run the old mysql binaries. the only files in the old mysql folder is the 'data' and 'keyring'

Comment: What is in those directores?

Comment: Just updated my question above.

Comment: @ChadH - Run `du` on each so we can see the tree structure under them.